# Upload file Servlet on hardcoded server path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, fileoutputstream

I have a .jsp page that show a file browser and a upload button and a Servlet that should upload the file to server . The problem is that the file is uploaded to a temporary folder but I need it to be uploaded on a specific path on the server, but the path isn`t recognized.

UploadServlet: the doPost method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        // get access to file that is uploaded from client
        Part p1 = request.getPart("file");
        InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();

        String filename = getFilename(p1);

        // get temporary path - this works but it saves on a tmp folder...
        //String outputfile = this.getServletContext().getRealPath(filename);  // get path on the server

        //hardcoded path on which I have to save my file
        String outputfile = "http://localhost:8080/Tutorial2/Upload/" + filename;

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (outputfile);

        // write bytes taken from uploaded file to target file
        int ch = is.read();
        while (ch != -1) {
             os.write(ch);
             ch = is.read();
        }
        os.close();
        out.println("<h3>File uploaded successfully!</h3>");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
       out.println("Exception -->" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally { 
        out.close();
    }
}

private static String getFilename(Part part) {
    for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The .jsp page

```
  <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select File : </td>
            <td><input  name="file" type="file"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>
```

I've seen many posts on this matter but neither helped me. When i run my servlet i get an exception at `FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (outputfile);` - `Exception -->http:\localhost:8080\Tutorial2\Upload\SvnBridge.exe (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`. Searched for this and didn't find anything relevant. I don't know if it helps but I use Servlet 3.0 and Apache Tomcat v7.

Do you have any ideea why can`t I write my file to the path above?

Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar Question and answer
[How to set the path to "context path" for uploaded files using Apache Common fileupload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901961/how-to-set-the-path-to-context-path-for-uploaded-files-using-apache-common-fil)

Use java.io.File

```
String relativeWebPath = "/WEB-INF/uploads";
String absoluteFilePath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File uploadedFile = new File(absoluteFilePath, FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName()));
// ...
```

Comment: I remember going thru the link above, but I think back then my servlet had other structure... anyways .. thanks a lot .. it works perfectly .. but I must say I was expecting the file to be copied in my eclipse workspace project folder but instead it was copied in 'D:\workspaceEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Tutorial2\Upload\', but it's ok as long as I can access it with 'http://localhost:8080/Tutorial2/Upload/[name of file]'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at exception, it indicates that problem is because of path not configured properly.
So you can use

```
File targetFile = new File(targetPath, filename) ;  // target path is hard coded for you.
```

as this will take more care of the path.