# How to write a file to resource/images folder of the app?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I would like to upload an image and store it on the server, and later to show it with h:graphicImage? I would like to store it in "resources/images" of the app. I am using glassfish 4. Right now, the file goes to "domain1\generated\jsp\FileUpload". Thank you

My form

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:messages/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="File:"/>
            <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{uploadPage.uploadedFile}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Upload File" action="#{uploadPage.uploadFile}"/>
</h:form>
```

My bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UploadPage {       
    private Part uploadedFile; 

    public void uploadFile(){
       File file = File.createTempFile("somefilename-", ".jpg", new File("C:\\var\\webapp\\images"));
    uploadedFile.write(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> *I would like to store it in "resources/images" of the app*

No, please don't. The WAR deploy space isn't intented as permanent file storage location. All of those uploaded files would get lost whenever you redeploy the webapp for the very simple reason that they are not contained in the original WAR. See for an elaborate explanation also this answer on a very closely related question: [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096).

---

> *Right now, the file goes to "domain1\generated\jsp\FileUpload".*

Because you specified a relative path in `Part#write()`. It becomes relative to the current working directory which you have no control over. See for an elaborate explanation also this related answer: [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream/2308388#2308388). You need to specify an absolute path, in other words, start the path with `/`.

---

Given that you're using Glassfish, the answer in [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096) should also do it for you. In a nutshell:

1. Create a `/var/webapp/images` folder. Note that this path is just examplary and fully free to your choice. Also note that when you're using Windows with a `C:\` disk, then this path is equivalent to `C:\var\webapp\images`.
2. Save the uploaded file in there.

   ```
   Path file = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get("/var/webapp/images"), "somefilename-", ".jpg", );

   try (InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream()) {
       Files.copy(input, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
   }

   imageFileName = file.getFileName().toString();
   // ...
   ```

   *(note: `Files#createTempFile()` is being used to autogenerate an unique filename, otherwise a previously uploaded file would get overwritten when the new uploaded file (by coincidence) has exactly the same filename)*
3. Tell GlassFish to register a virtual host on `/var/webapp/images` so that all files are available on `http://example.com/images` by adding the following entry to `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` of the webapp:

   ```xml
   <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=/var/webapp" />
   ```

   *(note: `alternatedocroot_1` must be exactly like that, keep it unmodified, if you have multiple, name it `alternatedocroot_2`, etc; also note that the `/images` part should indeed not be included in `dir` attribute, this is not a typo)*
4. Now you can display it as follows:

   ```html
   <h:graphicImage value="/images/#{bean.imageFileName}" />
   ```

   *(note: use `value` attribute, not `name` attribute)*

Comment: I get java.io.FileNotFoundException for No. 2. and SEVERE:   enterprise.deployment.backend.invalidDescriptorFailure
SEVERE:   enterprise.deployment.backend.saxParserError
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [FileUpload]
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing for No. 3

Comment: As to 2, make sure that the folders are already prepared. As to 4, I didn't said that it has to go in `web.xml`. It has to go in `glassfish-web.xml`. In Eclipse/Netbeans with official GlassFish plugin it should already be autocreated in the project when the project is associated with GlassFish as target runtime. Otherwise, create one yourself.

Comment: the folders  are  created I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\FileUpload\c:\var\webapp\images\somefilename-8202982476788377654.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) and there are files in the folder, but they are 0 bytes

Comment: The path is indeed wrong. It should have been `c:\var\webapp\i‌​mages\somefilename-8202982476788377654.jpg`

Comment: I just copied the file to the correct new folder and deleted the file in the default folder for uploading. Thanks

Comment: This is a great answer, however, you may also want to consider saving the image in a DB as a BLOB. This will all you to easily incorporate the upload, saving and retrieval in a transactional context.

Comment: @NBW: indeed, but OP explicitly asked to save in disk, not in DB.

Comment: WARNING: `File.createTempFile()` guarantees uniqueness of name only during the current invocation of the virtual machine. Therefore if you use this method for permanent storage of files (and not temp, as the method name suggests), then you need to ensure that the first argument of this method (generated filename prefix) remains unique beyond the lifespan of the VM (i.e., after restarting your server).

Comment: It seems Glassfish implementation does not support absolute paths, did you ever get this to save in the correct directory? It seems from your comments that you had to copy the file manually in the end? If you got it to work please provide update as I'm trying to achieve the same

Comment: @DTs No, I could not make it.

Comment: @BalusC, Please how do one achieve this with Apache?

Comment: @Ayodeji: Apache is the name of a software company. I gather you mean its Tomcat product? Nonetheless, the server-independent way is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18664579

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't able to get it working with `Path#write` in glassfish, so I used `Path#getInputStream` as follows:

```
public void upload(){
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            String filename = getFilename(uploadedFile);
            File file = new File("/var/webapp/images/"+filename);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(uploadedFile.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            int x;
            while((x = bis.read())!= -1){
                bos.write(x);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally{
            try {
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

private static String getFilename(Part part) {
        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```