# Glassfish 4.1.1 - alternatedocroot_1

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4, document-root

Is it still possible to serve files from an external folder with Glassfish 4 and the alternatedocroot_n property?

In my web.xml file I have :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>alternatedocroot_1</param-name>
    <param-value>from=images/* dir=/web/files/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then in an xhtml view I have :

```
<h:graphicImage name="/images/#{item.filename}"/>
```

But it returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is still possible...

But you have to set it up in the file `glassfish-web.xml`. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=/tmp " />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This example means, that you should have a folder named `images` in `/tmp` and when you access e.g. `/images/bla.jpg` in your webapp, it should reference `/tmp/images/bla.jpg`.

Also it doesn't make sense to set the `name` of the image, you have to set the `value`:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/images/#{item.filename}"/>
```

**See also:**

- [Glassfish docs - Alternate Document Roots](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4496/geqpl/index.html)
- [Alternate docroot not working on glassfish 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617517/alternate-docroot-not-working-on-glassfish-4)
- [GlassFish 4.1 alternatedocroot, Access static contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610625/glassfish-4-1-alternatedocroot-access-static-contents)
- [How should GlassFish alternatedocroot path be to display an image in h:graphicImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963557/how-should-glassfish-alternatedocroot-path-be-to-display-an-image-in-hgraphicim)
- [How to display images located in glass fish folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981640/how-to-display-images-located-in-glass-fish-folder)